# Add Primary key (new column) to an existing table with data

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

We have a table `B` which gets data from a another table `A` (another DB), source table `A` have introduced a new column and made that as Primary Key,
so Now we are making DDL changes to our table to add a new column and make it as Primary key column

Since our table `B` already has some data present,

I am looking for best approach to do this activity

can I do this?

add new column to our Table 'B', create Unique Index on the new column, once we have the data flowing in to new column we created on table `B`  then we'll make that column as Primary Key.

need your suggestions please

Comment: Please [edit] the question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the issue; the `ALTER TABLE` statements you used to modify the source table; an English description (not code) of the logic that you want to implement; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output. If you do not explain what you are starting with and what you expect the result to be then it is very difficult to answer the question; so help us to help you and provide a complete example.

Comment: There is a possibility to add a constraint enabled without validation. I did that especially for foreign key: alter table x_table add cosntraint x_constraint_fk (...) references rx_table (...) enable novalidate. Not sure if this may work for a primary key, for I think the columns must already be filled-in and the index built so that a primary key may be enabled, and that also implies validation.

Answer (score 2):

The question is: can you fill existing table `B` *future* primary key column with values that correspond to table `A`'s newly added primary key column? If so:

- alter table `B` and add a new column
- fill it with table `A` primary key values
- alter table `B` and apply primary key constraint to newly added column

If not, then: can you *make up* these value? For example, put a sequence in there or anything else that makes sense, and that won't collide with future primary key values in table `A`? If so, do that.

If not, then newly added "primary key" column must remain empty, which means that that column can **NOT** be a primary key as primary keys don't allow `null` values. But, you can make it a **unique key** instead as it allows `null`  values (that would be for "old", existing rows), but newly added rows will have to have unique values in that column (that shouldn't be a problem, as far as I understood).

Answer (score 0):

Just curious if you can use this approach.

### Assumptions:

1. Table B has a Primary Key b_pk on a specific column.
2. Table B is not a huge table with million rows.
3. Data copied from Table A to Table B is also not too large.
4. Please ensure that Table A column data you are creating in Table B should
   adhere to Primary key rules (each row data in that column should be unique).

### Steps

Export backup table B.
Alter table B drop constraint b_pk;

```
Alter table B add (<column name from A> <data type>)

Alter table B add constraint b_pk primary key (<column_name from A>);

insert into B (col1, col2,....)
select col1, col2,.... from A;
```

Try it and let me know.